# Is it possible to edit a non PostGIS layer within Lizmap?

Tags: qgis, postgis, web-mapping, lizmap

I have a running LizMap + Qgis Server configuration (but I am only the frontend admin, another dude is in charge of the backend server therefore I can't access to logs easely).

Our set-up is aimed to produce a tool intented to opperate multiple map projects.

As I first draw I've set-up a project within my desktop QGIS with lizmap extension.

I have some base layers and a layer I want to make editable . All layers are shp layers.
When I am within the "edit layer" tab of lizmap extension I can't select any layer.

I've done some reading and from what I understood it is only possible to made editable within LizMap web client PostGIS layer.

Then I managed to create a PostGIS layer and made it editable within le Lizmap extension.

But I have some error now within LizMap Web client to edit it. Please see attached screenshot:
[image]

From what i've read, it may be because of the initial configuration of LizMap web client where I should add connexion details to a specific PostGIS database.

In the end I have somes questions:

- Is it possible to edit a layer within a new PostGis Database (non existing when the Lizmap set-up was done)?
- Is it possible to edit a layer in another format than a PostGis database layer?

Comment: Can you please tell me the URL where you read "the initial configuration of Lizmap about specific postgis database" ? I would need to rephrase the sentence because no, it's not needed to edit Lizmap configuration to make the layer editable. Thanks. You need to edit your question by telling us what is the error you have.

Comment: Here you can see the bug:  
https://ibb.co/JnnZVSm

The process bar never ends to load

Comment: Please edit your question with the screenshot and logs (QGIS Server logs, Lizmap logs on the server (not the admin panel), maybe Javascript logs)

Comment: I've edited my initial post to make it more understandable (I hope). For logs, I have no direct access. The only thing I can get is the error I can see within Firefox: 
Code 500 internal Jelix error
Here a link to full error code: https://pastebin.com/QZ4FSfMJ

Comment: Without accessing the logs, we won't be able to detect what was wrong. If you really can't access the log, start by a very simple postgresql layer. Can you display it ? Can you disply its popup ? Can you have a single text field and edit it ? Does it have a valid primary key ? etc ... Having logs would help and edit your question with additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if the layer is editable in the properties of the qgis project (not read-only) ?

Also add write permissions to the user on the layer in postgis. Then save the connection information in the qgis Project[image]

Comment: Hi thx, 

Yes I've checked and none of my layers are read only. 

For your other comment, I would like guest to be able to edit the layer (it's a public project). 

As for the connexion information, I didn't find this window yet...

Comment: Update, I've found the connexion window and saved connexion information. But result is the same 500 error

Comment: Editing the connection window has NO effect on layers already loaded in the QGIS project. To make this change, you need to right-click on the layer and to "change datasource". You would need to tell us what is the error 500. (just answering if this topic is raised again later)